# Wordpress Meta Query two values to compare

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to compare two values for a meta_query? If the value equals a date earlier that todays date or null

```
 'meta_query' => array(
    $private_check,
    array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'type' => 'date',
    'compare' => '<' // All past posts.
  )
```

so compare '<' or null

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a quick google search, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109390/wordpress-meta-query-possible-to-use-multiple-or-nested-meta-query-arguments), which seems to be dealing with something similar (but not quite) to what you are looking at.

I don't have any experience with this, but I quick look at the [wordpress meta-query codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)   showed the following accepted arguments exist:

> The following arguments can be passed in a key=>value paired array.
>
> **meta_compare (string)** - Operator to test the 'meta_value'. Possible values are '!=', '>', '>=', '<', or '<='. Default value is
>   '='.

Comment: Thanks that link helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do this with 'relation' => 'AND'

Thanks to @gersande

Comment: :) I'm glad I could help. You can press my response as the answer, if you like? (Or not, since it was more of an intermediary step.) Glad I could help!!